# Active admin and devise-security - how to change layout for password_expired page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an app with active admin and device. All device's views(for logging, changing password, etc) use active admin layout.

I added device-security gem, and view: `views/devise/password_expired/show.html.haml` doesn't use that layout.

How can I add the active admin layout to this view?